# how to dispose once done

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to dispose the instance once the function is finished. something with "using" i think...

also
i want to add each name to an array .

i try:

```
      using(  Database db = new Database())

    public string[] FindNameByLength(int minimumCharNumber)
    {

        try{
        var query = from u in db.Users
                    where u.FullName.Length > minimumCharNumber
                    select u.FullName;


        string[] namesLength;
        int counter;

        foreach (var s in query)
        {
            namesLength.Concat(new[] {s });
        }
        return namesLength;
        }
        finally IDisposable(db).dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: What is it that you want to dispose of?

Comment: What are you trying to dispose? Your code wouldn't compile.

Comment: Database db = new Database()

Comment: You are asking two questions which are not connected in a meaningfull way. Have you read this-  http://stackoverflow.com/about ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx): Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of IDisposable objects.

As a rule, when you use an IDisposable object, you should declare and instantiate it in a using statement. The using statement calls the Dispose method on the object in the correct way, and (when you use it as shown earlier) it also causes the object itself to go out of scope as soon as Dispose is called. Within the using block, the object is read-only and cannot be modified or reassigned.

**The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object. You can achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the using statement is translated by the compiler.**

So, either use **using block**:

```
using (Database db = new Database())
{

}
```

Or, you can use **try-finally**:

```
  Database db = new Database();
  try
  {

  }
  finally
  {
    if (db != null)
      ((IDisposable)db).Dispose();
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

Put

```
using(...)
{
    ...
}
```

inside your function. Also do not explicitly call `Dispose`.

```
public string[] FindNameByLength(int minimumCharNumber)
{
    using (Database db = new Database())
    {
        var query = from u in db.Users
                    where u.FullName.Length > minimumCharNumber
                    select u.FullName;

        string[] namesLength;
        int counter;

        foreach (var s in query)
        {
            namesLength.Concat(new[] { s });
        }

        return namesLength;
    }
}
```

`Finally` is also not needed here, as `Dispose` will always be called, no matter how you exit the `using` scope (`return`, exception, `}`).

Comment: But remember to close the connection to the database before the end of the using. Something like db.Close() - or the connection will remain open and the object will not be disposed.

Comment: @KBoek Actually, most implementations of database connection-type objects internally call `Close()` when `Dispose()` is called. We don't know exactly what `Database` is, but it's probably a good guess that the above applies.

Comment: @KBoek Based on the LINQ syntax, I assumed `Database` represents an entity framework context. Disposing the context does all the required stuff (closing connection to DB...etc.)

Comment: @AndrewBarber IMHO such assumptions are wrong. It's the responsibility of the developer to make sure that all references to an object are deleted before the object is disposed. Since we don't know what kind of db were talking about here, it's good to remind the questioner about this. Remember that objects that still have a reference won't be GC'd!

Comment: @KBoek No, that is not correct. Deleting references is pointless here, and it actually *prevents* you from disposing it. Also, disposing/closing has *nothing whatsoever* to do with whether an object is GC'ed.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Disagree; but let's not take that discussion here. For what other reason than GC would you dispose?

Comment: @KBoek I think you completely misunderstand disposing and GC. GC is about clearing up managed memory. Disposing is about clearing up *unmanaged* resources. They are quite different things. If what you say is correct, why doesn't *every* .NET class have a `Dispose()` method?

Comment: @AndrewBarber I agree my comment was misleading although I meant what you wrote about GC. But my point in my 2nd comment from above is that you can never assume, like you and ken2k did. Assuming you don't have to call db.Close() may cause you trouble. I just wanted to remind about that so that he could verify it.

Comment: @KBoek Well, *you* are assuming that the `Database` object even *has* a method called `Close()`... it's not an illogical assumption to make here. Based on the *same* assumption, it's further not illogical to assume this is an EF Context.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24460/discussion-between-kboek-and-andrew-barber)